# What's the difference between rowid vs docid in sqlite fts table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

Is there any advantage of using one over the other?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are similar, except for a small quirk.

Look at section 1.3 of this document : 
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html